# Techniques for rendering rotated text in emacs?

Tags: rendering

What techniques exist to render rotated text in emacs?  By this I mean physical rotation of text by an arbitrary angle and shown inline in a buffer as shown here:

[image: two examples of rotated text]

(alignment of text in my sample is not significant)

Inserting an SVG image containing the rotated text comes to mind, but that is subject to emacs being built with SVG and naturally it wouldn't enable text selection.  Maybe it could still accommodate search if shown as an overlay.

I'm open to any suggestions.  Even limited solutions are highly relevant.  For example: if emacs could rotate individual glyphs/characters, but only rotated by 90 degrees or mirrored that would still be plenty useful!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the use case you have in mind?

Comment: @Dan Labels for rendering an axis of dense two-dimensional content (charts and tabular data).  It would prescribe overlapping of rectangular bounding boxes, but: *baby steps*  :-)  The question stands on its own and is purely exploratory.

Comment: @ebpa, have you explored this question more? Did you find anything interesting?

Comment: @Slackware it's been in the back of my mind,  but svg is the best solution I have come up with.